# Kafka offset resets sometimes after consumer restart

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka topic with 4 partitions and 4 consumers with same Consumer Group ID.
All consumers restart every night, first at 4:00 a.m., second at 4:15 a.m and others at 4:30 and 4:45 (it's our admins' rules I can do nothing with it).
Some days offset for some partitions reset and consumers after restart read all the messages starting with offset 0. Some days it not happens. Any ideas where the problem is?
Consumers are in Go.

Kafka config:

```
conf := kafka.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers:  cfg.Kafka.BootstrapServers,
        GroupID:  cfg.Kafka.ConsumerGroup,
        Topic:    cfg.Kafka.Topic,
        MinBytes: 10e3, // 10KB
        MaxBytes: 32e6, // 10MB
    }
```

Read the message:

```
for {
        m, err := reader.ReadMessage(context.Background())
        if err != nil {
            go log.Error(componentName, actionName, -123753, err.Error(), "Ошибка чтения сообщения с кафки", "", "", string(m.Value), nil)
            continue
        }
        log.Warn(componentName, actionName, "Обработка сообщения", "START", "", "", map[string]interface{}{"offset": m.Offset, "partition": m.Partition}, nil)
        var msg model.KafkaMessage

        err = json.Unmarshal(m.Value, &msg)
        if err != nil {
            go log.Error(componentName, actionName, -123754, err.Error(), "Ошибка парсинга сообщения", "", "", string(m.Value), nil)
            continue
        }

        _service := service.NewService(log, cfg)
        currentNumAttempts := 0 
        maxNumAttempt := 3      

        for currentNumAttempts < maxNumAttempt {
            currentNumAttempts++
            err = _service.UpdateNumberInColvir(msg)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }
            break
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is your consumer's commit message config? And `__consumer_offsets` topic `cleanup.policy` config?  can you add those?

Comment: ReadMessage method from lib github.com/segmentio/kafka-go commit messages automatically. I'll ask admins for topic config.

Comment: And cleanup.policy is DELETE.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment *`And cleanup.policy is DELETE`* Following can be happened.

`__consumer_offsets` topic keeps the track of last committed offset per topic partition of your consumer group.

`cleanup.policy = delete` means your `__consumer_offsets` topic partition logs delete after [`retention.ms`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_retention.ms).

So, your consumers not consumed any message for `retention.ms` period, your `__consumer_offset` topic will not be updated and all message in the offset topic will be deleted. Then there is no any track to your consumer group in `__consumer_offsets` topic. So, Kafka thinks it is as a new consumer group to the topic partition and start to read messages from start.

NOTE - [`cleanup.policy`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_cleanup.policy) should be `compact` for `__consumer.offsets` topic.